# What are the security concerns when using AD distribution groups to control access to program features?

Tags: .net, security, active-directory, roles

I'm relatively new to using AD, and I'm using group memberships to control what features and functions are loaded/visible to a given user, both in web and desktop applications.

AD has security groups and distribution groups, and I'm using some of each to get fine-grained discrimination among roles.

What should be my concerns about using distribution groups in this way?

Comment: Oh, just remember one thing.  If you are going to define a lot of different groups (say over 1000 groups) assigned to the users for your role purpose, you should really use distribution groups rather than security group.  The reason is that there is a hard limit on how many security groups a user can belong to but there is no limit on how many distribution groups a user can belong to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might consider looking at [AzMan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649313.aspx) (Authorization Manager).

It can be tied to active directory accounts and completely stored within AD.  AzMan provides a lot more fine grained control over Roles and even Actions allowed.  In short you would code your apps to test if the user is authorized for particular Actions.  When creating Roles you would assign one or more actions to that role.

This would allow you to mix and match actions in various roles as necessary without having to change your code base.   I've used it extensively and it's pretty good.

The downside to just using regular AD groups is that you might end up with dozens or even hundreds (depending on the complexity of your apps) roles that pollute the AD space.

For example, let's say you want to have a security check before allowing an account to be deleted.  In AzMan you would create an AccountDelete action and assign that action to one or more roles like Administrator, Account Administrator, etc.

In AD you would have to create a new group altogether and assign it out.  This gets very complicated very quickly.

Comment: +1 Thanks, Chris - I actually won't be adding new groups to AD, I'm just using existing group memberships. I'm just wondering if using distribution groups has specific problems (like users can add themselves or something)

Comment: Agree to use AzMan if Jay just wants to show/hide some features on the UI based on the group membership.  AzMan also allows you to define dynamic group, where the group membership is defined by a LDAP filter.  This may be useful to you if you want to define a group like including all the AD users whose manager is "Jane.Doe".

Comment: What AzMan library are you using?  Did you use AzRoles.dll?  I found it's very buggy.  Is there any nicer managed library you recommend?

Comment: @Harvey: We had some issues back in 2005/06 but those problems went away with server 2008.